# Compile C code with out making a .C file

Tags: php, gcc, cygwin

I am try to compile a 'C' code in php. I am using windowsXP and cygwin to compile the code. I run the code as:

**PHP Code**

```
$a = ' int main(){ int i; for(i= 0;i!=10;i++) printf("Its Worked");return 0;}';

$o = exec('echo '.$a.' | c:\cygwin\bin\gcc-3 -xc - -o "c:\o\ank.exe"', $errD , $err);
```

It is perfectly work and make a .exe file as I want.

but if there is a new line in the code i.e. the code is now

```
$a = ' int main()
{ 
int i;
for(i= 0;i!=10;i++)
 printf("Its Worked");
return 0;
} ';

$o = exec('echo '.$a.' | c:\cygwin\bin\gcc-3 -xc - -o "c:\o\ank.exe"', $errD , $err);
```

It gives compile error.

Can some one tell me the way to compile such code with out making a .c file. One more problem with this I can not include any header file because it need a new line.

It is also not recognized special characters like '%' etc.

All answers and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you want us to guess the error you get?!

Comment: You could probably get crafty with echo and escapeshellarg, though the very idea of this makes me cry a little.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It does not create .exe file and probably it consider all new lines and run only first line as in the code 'int main()' which does not make any sense to compile.

Comment: @Corbin do u hv any idea to solve this problem

Comment: @CodeBreaker i do hv a gud guess. The problem is that the shell is misunderstanding your giant chunk of text.  You need to properly escape it.  escapeshellarg is designed to escape shell arguments.  In other words, make the shell understand your string correctly.

Comment: Why can't you simply save the code in a temporary file?

Comment: @Corbin I tried as you say as putting '\' (back slash) at end of each line but I have still same problem

Comment: $ThiefMaster I don't want to make .c file.

Comment: Making a temporary file is the correct thing to do in this situation.  And a new line is not the only special character.  You'll have to escape all special characters.  As I said before, look at escapeshellarg.

Comment: It is ironic your name is "Code Breaker" :))

Comment: @"Code Breaker" dont't create a hell for youself, and maybe others to come after you. Do what ThiefMaster says, and write to a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

use before exc command:
$a = preg_replace("/\n/",' ',$a); // remove all new line so the code actually run contains one line only...